# Edit AWS Application Load Balancer listener rules programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, elastic-load-balancer, amazon-elb

Is there a way to edit the listener rules (say the host name for example) of an Application Load Balancer programmatically?

Comment: Sure, why not? Start with https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/APIReference/API_CreateRule.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteRule.html

Comment: Let's say I have all the code ready and I need to run this code on demand. Would you deploy the code as a console app, put it on some EC2, or rather use an AWS Lambda function?